# Как можно доставать ключи из одного словаря и преобразовывать их в json

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, vkontakte-api, словари

Есть словарь...

```
CLASSES = {
    '1':'class-1',
    '2':'class-2',
    '3':'class-3',
    '4':'class-4',
    '5':'class-5',
    '6':'class-6',
    '7':'class-7',
    '8':'class-8',
    '9':'class-9',
    '10':'class-10',
    '11':'class-11',
}
```

Как доставать ключи по очереди из этого словаря и преобразовывать их в json по типу...

```
keyboard_classes = {
    "one_time": False,
    "buttons": [
        [{
                "action": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "label": "1 ключ из словаря"
                },
                "color": "positive"
            },
            {
                    "action": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "label": "2 ключ из словаря"
                    },
                    "color": "positive"
                },
            {
                    "action": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "label": "3 ключ из словаря"
                    },
                    "color": "positive"
                },
            {
                    "action": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "label": "4 ключ из словаря"
                    },
                    "color": "positive"
                },
        ],
        [{
                "action": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "label": "5 ключ из словаря"
                },
                "color": "positive"
            },
            {
                    "action": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "label": "6 ключ из словаря"
                    },
                    "color": "positive"
                },
            {
                    "action": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "label": "7 ключ из словаря"
                    },
                    "color": "positive"
                },
            {
                    "action": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "label": "8 ключ из словаря"
                    },
                    "color": "positive"
                },
        ],
        # и так далее...
    ]
}
```

Comment: можете пояснить как `'class-1'` превратилось в `"1 ключ из словаря"`? Или откуда берется `"1 ключ из словаря"` ?

Comment: это для примера, чтобы новички смогли понять. 1 ключ из словаря = "1", 2 ключ из словаря = "2" и тд.

Comment: и class-1 это значение словаря, а не ключ. надо чтобы в json'е был ключ.

Comment: т.е. значения словаря в JSON не должны попадать вообще? только ключи?

Comment: Да, только ключи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для гибкости можно воспользоваться модулем [dpath](https://pypi.org/project/dpath/):

```
from copy import deepcopy
import dpath.util as DU      #   pip install dpath


template = {
    "action": {
        "type": "text",
        "label": "???"
    },
    "color": "positive"
}

def gen_entry(val, template=template, path="/action/label"):
    d = deepcopy(template)
    DU.set(d, path, val)
    return d


keys = list(CLASSES.keys())
bucket_size = 4


buttons = [[gen_entry(key, template=template, path="/action/label")
            for key in keys[i:i+bucket_size]]
           for i in range(0, len(keys), bucket_size)]

keyboard_classes = dict(
    one_time=False,
    buttons=buttons
)
```

---

результат:

```
In [51]: print(json.dumps(keyboard_classes, indent=2))
{
  "one_time": false,
  "buttons": [
    [
      {
        "action": {
          "type": "text",
          "label": "1"
        },
        "color": "positive"
      },
      {
        "action": {
          "type": "text",
          "label": "2"
        },
        "color": "positive"
      },
      {
        "action": {
          "type": "text",
          "label": "3"
        },
        "color": "positive"
      },
      {
        "action": {
          "type": "text",
          "label": "4"
        },
        "color": "positive"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "action": {
          "type": "text",
          "label": "5"
        },
        "color": "positive"
      },
      {
        "action": {
          "type": "text",
          "label": "6"
        },
        "color": "positive"
      },
      {
        "action": {
          "type": "text",
          "label": "7"
        },
        "color": "positive"
      },
      {
        "action": {
          "type": "text",
          "label": "8"
        },
        "color": "positive"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "action": {
          "type": "text",
          "label": "9"
        },
        "color": "positive"
      },
      {
        "action": {
          "type": "text",
          "label": "10"
        },
        "color": "positive"
      },
      {
        "action": {
          "type": "text",
          "label": "11"
        },
        "color": "positive"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

CLASSES = {
    '1':'class-1',
    '2':'class-2',
    '3':'class-3',
    '4':'class-4',
    '5':'class-5',
    '6':'class-6',
    '7':'class-7',
    '8':'class-8',
    '9':'class-9',
    '10':'class-10',
    '11':'class-11',
}

result = json.dumps(CLASSES, indent=4)


print(result)
```

Есть модуль json, который по-моему решает вашу проблему, код не тестировал, пробуйте.

Answer (score 0):

Без сторонних библиотек.

```py
from itertools import islice


keyboard_classes = {
    "one_time": False,
    "buttons": [
        [
            {
                "action": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "label": key
                },
                "color": "positive"
            }
            for key in part
        ]
        for part in (islice(CLASSES, i, i + 4) for i in range(0, len(CLASSES), 4))
    ]
}
```